# MLMediaLibrary video URL for 'Live Photos' macOS 10.13

Tags: macos, cocoa, url, media-library, apple-live-photos

I'm using **MLMediaLibrary** on *macOS 10.13* to access the media from the **Apple Photos app** (local photos library).
I can get all necessary file URLs (edited, original,thumbnail image) from the **NLMediaObject**. I can even get the video URL for unedited **'Live Photos'** by
accessing the attributes property of **MLMediaObject**:

```
[myMediaObject.attributes valueForKey:@"videoComplURL"];
```

The only issue I have is, if the **'Live Photo'** was edited in **Photos app**, the videoComplURL key is not there anymore in the attributes of the **MLMediaObject**.
If it's unedited I can get the videoComplURL. When I revert back to original from an edited **'Live Photo'** in **Photos app** I see the videoComplURL again.
My question is now : How can I get the video URL for an edited **'Live Photo'** on *macOS 10.13* by using **MLMediaLibrary**? Is there any other library I can use to get the **Albums** and **Collections** from **Apples Photo app** with the media content?

Thx